# .then not waiting for return function when using cordovaGeolocation

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I turn once again to StackOverFlow in my pursuit to learn Javascript and Ionic.

I have created the following factory function:

```
.factory('GeoService', function($ionicPlatform, $cordovaGeolocation) {

  var positionOptions = {timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: true};

  return {
    getPosition: function() {
      return $ionicPlatform.ready()
        .then(function() {
          return $cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(positionOptions);
        })
    }
  };

});
```

Which obtains the GPS coordinates. To call this function I am doing the following:

```
        GeoService.getPosition()
            .then(function(position) {
                //Obtain geolocation information
                console.dir(position.coords)

                return position.coords;
            }, function(err) {
                console.log('getCurrentPosition error: ' + err);
            }).then(function(data) {
                console.dir(data)

                //make http request with the information
            })
```

The issue that I have is that the second .then is not waiting for the GeoService.getPosition() to resolve before attempting to send the information via http. I suspect I need to use something along the lines of q.all but I am just not sure.

Many thanks

Comment: It should work fine. I'm guessing that there is an issue within getPosition where it resolves prematurely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define your own promise

```
.factory('GeoService', function($q,$ionicPlatform, $cordovaGeolocation) {


  function getPosition(){

    return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
        var positionOptions = {timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: true};
        $cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(positionOptions)
        .then(function(position){
             resolve(position); 
        }, function(error){
           reject(error); 
        }); 
    })

  } 
  return {
    getPosition: getPosition
  };

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `.then()` in `GeoService.getPosition()` but you are not returning a Promise!! Try this:

```
.factory('GeoService', function($ionicPlatform, $cordovaGeolocation) {

  var positionOptions = {timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: true};

  return {
    getPosition: function() {
      return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        $ionicPlatform.ready()
          .then(function() {
            $cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(positionOptions)
              .then(function(position) {
                resolve(position);
              });
          })
      }
  };

});
```